# ¿Cómo obtener valor de un select Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, select, thymeleaf

Tengo un formulario denominado **listaDepartamentos.html**.

```
<form action="/search" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${departamentos}" method="post">
      <select name="nombreDept">
            <option th:each="Item : ${departamentosSelect}"
              th:value="${Item.nombre}" 
              th:text="${Item.nombre}"
              th:selected="true"
              />
          </select>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

Y una página html que recoge el valor seleccionado (**search.html**).

```
<b>Resultado</b>
    <p th:text="'nombre: ' + ${departamentos.nombre}" />
    <a href="/listaDepartamentos">Regresar</a>
    <div th:include="layout/footer"></div>
```

Mi **CrontrollerProyecto.java**

```
//...
@Controller
public class ControllerProyecto{

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerProyecto.class);

    @Autowired
    private DepartamentoService departamentoService;

//Formulario donde se depliega el select
 @GetMapping("/listaDepartamentos")
    public String departamentosForm(Model model){
//La lista esta llena
        List<Departamento> departamentosSelect = departamentoService.getAllDepartamentos();
        model.addAttribute("departamentosSelect",departamentosSelect);
        return "listaDepartamentos";
    }

//Donde se envia el valor seleccionado
    @PostMapping("/search")
    public String departamentosPost(@ModelAttribute("departamentos") Departamento departamentos) {
        LOGGER.info("Has elegido: "+departamentos);
        return "search";
    }

}
```

1. La lista de departamentos esta llena
2. En el formulario (listDepartamentos) se enlistan los departamentos correctamente.

**¿Cuál es el problema?** El problema es que al seleccionar el nombre del departameto manda null.

Ya he visto varios post sobre como usar un select, pero no logro hacer que obtenga el nombre.

[image: select]

[image: escoger valor]

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado:
En la página listaDepartamentos.html cambie el name="nombreDept" por name="nombre":

```
<form action="/search" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${departamentos}" method="post">
      <select name="nombre">
            <option th:each="Item : ${departamentosSelect}"
              th:value="${Item.nombre}" 
              th:text="${Item.nombre}"
              th:selected="false"
              />
          </select>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
    </form>
```

Y obtengo el nombre seleccionado:

[image: obtener valor del select]